# Need a query in Sqlalchemy with GROUP BY CASE

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

All i need is a simple query with GROUP BY CASE like

```
SELECT 
  COUNT([Personnel].[PERSONNEL_ID]) AS value,
  CASE 
    WHEN ([Personnel].[T_FIRSTNAME] = 'John') THEN 'John' 
    ELSE 'somethingelse' 
  END AS somelabel 
FROM [Personnel] 
GROUP BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN ([Personnel].[T_FIRSTNAME] = 'John') THEN 'John' 
    ELSE 'somethingelse' 
  END
```

in Sqlalchemy my query looks like this:

```
case_groups = case(
    [(HrPersonnel.T_FIRSTNAME=='John', 'John')],
    else_='somethingelse'
)

volunteers = session_mssql.query(
    func.count(HrPersonnel.S_HR_PERSONNEL_ID).label('value'),
    case_groups.label('somelabel'))\
    .group_by(case_groups)\
    .all()
```

mssql server executes the query without any problem (engine.connect().execute(text_query))

but Sqlalchemy ORM query gives me an error.

> File
>   "c:\projects\sa_test\eggs\sqlalchemy-0.9.2-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py",
>   line 425, in do_execute cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
>   sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Column
>   'Personnel.T_FIRSTNAME' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>   (8120) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)") 
>   u'SELECT count([Personnel].[PERSONNEL_ID]) AS value, CASE WHEN
>   ([Personnel].[T_FIRSTNAME] = ?) THEN ? ELSE ? END AS somelabel \nFROM
>   [Personnel] GROUP BY CASE WHEN ([Personnel].[T_FIRSTNAME] = ?) THEN ?
>   ELSE ? END' ('John', 'John', 'somethingelse', 'John', 'John',
>   'somethingelse')

Why 'Personnel.T_FIRSTNAME' is invalid in the select list?

any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks,

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems.  any solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902172/sqlalchemy-query-in-mssql-programmingerror-invalid-odbc-bug

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer per se (although future readers may want to check [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/o4H3kalpAFk) on the SQLAlchemy Google Group), but I've had a similar issue recently and found a workaround.

Instead of executing the query directly, convert it into a string and execute that. For example:

```
session.execute(
    str(query.selectable.compile(compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
).fetchall()
```